# std::bind requires default constructor

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, c++11

Im working on a project to school(as namespace name may hint, it is 2D game) and Ive made a custom class called RangeInt(Range) which just wraps two variables of same type and made another class called Randomizer which wraps the C++11 standard random number generation and uses the RangeInt class to specify the range I want to generate the numbers.

Well anyways here is the code:

```c
    namespace game{
    template<class _Type>
    //very simple class representing virtual Range
    //of type _Type(template argument) and storing
    //upper and lower bound
    class Range{
        public:
        typedef _Type TemplateParam;
        //value sto use of type _Type
        _Type first, second;

        //copy constructor:
        Range(const Range& rng)
        {
            first = rng.first;
            second = rng.second;
        }

        //move construct:
        Range(Range&& rng)
        {
            std::swap(*this, rng);
        }
        Range& operator=(const Range& range)
        {
            first = range.first;
            second = range.second;
            return *this;
        }
        Range& operator=(Range&& range)
        {
            std::swap(first, range.first);
            std::swap(second, range.second);
            return *this;
        }
        //constructor
        Range(_Type one, _Type two) : first(one), second(two) {}
        //returns two - one
        inline _Type getDifference() { return two - one; }
    };

    typedef Range<uint> RangeInt;
};
```

and the randomizer:

```c
namespace game{
    template <class _RNG = xorshift>
    class Randomizer_RNG{
        typedef _RNG random_generator;
        RangeInt rng;
        random_generator mt;
        std::uniform_int_distribution<> dist;
        //reinitialize the dist variable so it actually knows the new range
        void _changeDist()
        {
            dist = std::uniform_int_distribution<>(rng.first, rng.second);
        }
        public:
        //default constructor, set rng to maximum range and initialize
        //the xorshift with seed being current time and specify the
        //range for uniform_int_distribution
        Randomizer_RNG()
        {
            rng = game::RangeInt(0, std::numeric_limits<game::uint>::max());
            dist = std::uniform_int_distribution<>(range.first, range.second);
            mt.seed(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count());
        }
        //do the same as constructor above but with specified range
        explicit Randomizer_RNG(RangeInt range) : rng(range)
        {
            dist = std::uniform_int_distribution<>(rng.first, rng.second);
            mt.seed(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count());
        }
        //copy constructor
        Randomizer_RNG(const Randomizer_RNG& lhs)
        {
            dist = lhs.dist;
            mt = lhs.mt;
            rng = lhs.rng;
        }
        //move constructor
        Randomizer_RNG(Randomizer_RNG&& lhs)
        {
            std::swap(*this, lhs);
        }
        //reseed with current time
        inline void seed()
        {
            mt.seed(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count());
        }
        //reseed with specified value
        inline void seed(unsigned long long newSeed)
        {
            mt.seed(newSeed);
        }
        //default operator()
        uint32 operator()()
        {
            return dist(mt);
        }
        //return value generated in range of
        //<fitWithin.first, fitWithin.second>
        uint32 operator()(RangeInt&& fitWithin)
        {
            decltype(dist) l_dist(fitWithin.first, fitWithin.second);
            return l_dist(mt);
        }
        //the same as above, but with rvalue reference
        uint32 operator()(RangeInt& fitWithin)
        {
            decltype(dist) l_dist(fitWithin.first, fitWithin.second);
            return l_dist(mt);
        }
        //change range with reference
        void changeRange(const RangeInt& rng)
        {
            this->rng = rng;
            _changeDist();
        }
        //the same as above but with rvalue reference
        void changeRange(RangeInt&& rng)
        {
            std::swap(this->rng, rng);
            _changeDist();
        }
        //set the upper bound of the range and update rng
        void setUpperBound(RangeInt::TemplateParam upBound)
        {
            rng.second = upBound;
            _changeDist();
        }
        //set the lower bound of the range and update rng
        void setLowerBound(RangeInt::TemplateParam lowBound)
        {
            rng.first = lowBound;
            _changeDist();
        }
        //copy assignment
        Randomizer_RNG& operator=(const Randomizer_RNG& lhs)
        {
            _RETURN_IF_THIS(lhs, *this);    //if (*this == lhs)    return *this;
            rng = lhs.rng;
            changeRange(rng);
            return *this;
        }
        //move assignment
        Randomizer_RNG& operator=(Randomizer_RNG&& lhs)
        {
            dist = std::move(lhs.dist);
            rng = std::move(lhs.rng);
            mt = std::move(lhs.mt);
            return *this;
        }
    };
    typedef Randomizer_RNG<> Randomizer;
    typedef Randomizer_RNG<std::mt19937> Randomizer_Twist;
};
```

but when I do

```c
#include "randomizer.h"

int main()
{
    game::RangeInt rngI (14, 546);
    game::Randomizer rng = game::Randomizer(game::RangeInt(0, 100));
    auto func = std::bind(rng, rngI);
    std::cout << func();
    std::cin.get();
}
```

it pops compiler error:

```c
error C2512: 'game::Range<_Type>' : no appropriate default constructor available
with  
[  
_Type=game::uint  
]
```

And if I try to do:

```c
#include "randomizer.h"

int main()
{
    game::RangeInt rngI (14, 546);
    game::Randomizer rng = game::Randomizer(game::RangeInt(0, 100));
    auto func = std::bind(&rng, rngI);
    std::cout << func();
    std::cin.get();
}
```

it says:
    error C2679: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::_Do_call_ret<_Forced,_Ret,_Funx,_Btuple,_Ftuple>::type' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

So I wonder if Im doing something wrong or why does std::bind want default constructor from me for game::Range.

If my question is not clear or the code is not clear, let me know I will do my best.

PS: Im using Visual Studio 2012 so Variadic templates are not implemented(std::bind for instance has 378 overlaods)

Comment: Storing the result from `std::bind` into an `auto` variable might be the problem. Can you try `std::function<void()> func = std::bind(...);` instead?

Comment: I actually want it to return unsigned int(as the operator()s of return uint32) and `std::function<unsigned int()>` pops `'return' : cannot convert from 'std::_Do_call_ret<_Forced,_Ret,_Funx,_Btuple,_Ftuple>::type' to 'unsigned int'`  `_Forced = false, _Ret = void/*for some reason*/, _Funx = game::Randomizer<> *, _Btuple=std::tuple<game::Range<game::uint>>, _Ftuple=std::tuple<>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make it

```
Randomizer_RNG(const Randomizer_RNG& lhs)
   : dist(lhs.dist), mt(lhs.mt), rng(lhs.rng)
{}
```

or just drop this constructor altogether: the compiler-generated one is good enough.

As written, your constructor tries to default-construct `rng` first, and then assign to it. But, as the compiler tells you, `Range` doesn't provide a default constructor.

Comment: oh wow that was actually the problem, so indeed I was doing something wrong. Thank you sir!